# How to filter for rows using multiple conditions for strings

Tags: r, string

How can I filter rows in `df` based on multiple conditions with strings? I want to extract all rows with the string 'CH-4752' OR 'ER-9987'.

In other words, go from this:

```
df
```

```
identifier        unit

ABCD-CH-4752-01X  27  
ABCD-CH-4752-11X  15
ABCD-AZ-5155-01X  6
ABCD-ER-9987-01X  27  
ABCD-ER-9987-11X  15
ABCD-GH-5230-01X  72
ABCD-UI-9078-01X  9
ABCD-OP-7489-01X  88
```

to this:

```
df
```

```
identifier        unit

ABCD-CH-4752-01X  27  
ABCD-CH-4752-11X  15
ABCD-ER-9987-01X  27  
ABCD-ER-9987-11X  15
```

Comment: can you be more specific what "df" is? df is a common disk utility tool on unix but I'm guessing that's not what you mean...

Comment: df variable = dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this using `grep`

```
df[grep("CH-4752|ER-9987",df$identifier),]
        identifier unit
1 ABCD-CH-4752-01X   27
2 ABCD-CH-4752-11X   15
4 ABCD-ER-9987-01X   27
5 ABCD-ER-9987-11X   15
```

##### Data

```
df <- structure(list(identifier = c("ABCD-CH-4752-01X", "ABCD-CH-4752-11X",
"ABCD-AZ-5155-01X", "ABCD-ER-9987-01X", "ABCD-ER-9987-11X", "ABCD-GH-5230-01X",
"ABCD-UI-9078-01X", "ABCD-OP-7489-01X"), unit = c(27L, 15L, 6L,
27L, 15L, 72L, 9L, 88L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-8L))
```